# Error loading Variables stage.loaderInfo - AS3

Tags: variables, scope, stage

I have a Document class that loads variables from Facebook with the use of stage.loaderInfo

`var connect:FacebookConnectObject = new FacebookConnectObject( facebook, API_KEY, this.stage.loaderInfo );`

But when I change the Document class (with another one responsible for the layout of my app),  and try call the above from a movieclip that exists in my application with the use:

`var facebook_class:FacebookAp = new FaceBppkApp
addChild(facebook_class)` I get error

`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`

I believe the error comes fro this line

`this.stage.loaderInfo`

since I changed the scope...
How I am supposed to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

According to a post by Devonair: *Seems 99 times out of a 100 when people have a problem with a 1009 error, it's because the stage property is inaccessible.*

so I used this snippet

`public function start() {
    if
{(stage) init();}
    else
{ addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
 }
}`

`private function init(event:Event = null):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    // everything else...
}`

In case sb has the same problem...